# Using Dataverse Synapse Link as reference data for Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-stream-analytics, dataverse

We are trying to use our Dataverse data as reference data for our Azure Stream Analytics. The idea is to couple customer acitivities with their CRM profile to create meaningful actions for them. We are currently moving from DES to the Dataverse Synapse Link, and have created the data lake where data gets dumped and can see it in Synapse Studio. However, Stream Analytics does not take CDM format out-of-the-box. It seems it can only handle CSV (with headers) and Json formats.

What is the best approach to get our Dataverse data in as reference for Stream Analytics (and in real time as possible)? Should we create a custom deserializer, or use ADF or something else?

Comment: Is your CRM profile inside dynamics? This might be a long shot but you could try enabling TDS support for dynamics then try looking up against that https://arunpotti.com/2021/11/24/how-to-enable-disable-tds-endpoint-for-a-microsoft-dynamics-365-ce-online-environment/. It seems streaming can use Azure SQL as a lookup source, and it will be real time. Keep in mind that last time I used TDS it was somewhat unreliable, and you'll probably find it gets throttled.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for input. I am not sure how to use TDS as a SQL source. We do have it enabled and I can connect in PowerBI, but I don't see how to get it in as SQL database source?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-reference-data